# How to keep/wipe file on app update?

Tags: android, file, version, updates

I have `file A`, which is shared preferences. Authorisation details are stored in `file A`.
Some notes are stored in `file B`. When I am updating version of of app, I whish to wipe `file A`, but keep `file B`. I want to wipe file A, because I might want to change encription mechanizm to improve safty. But notes in file B might have important and long information, so i need save them betweeen versions.
file B

```
Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store a version Number in the resources file something like this

```
<string name="app_version">x.x.x</string>
```

Then save that version into `SharedPreferences` if it does not exist yet. Then when you start up your app compare your preference version to the resource version (that you will update before every release). If they do not match then your app has been updated, you can then execute your file modifications.

There is the one exception where the user can call Clear data from the OS. If that happens your code will execute again when the app is opened because all preferences would be cleared but there is no way from preventing that scenario.

Hope this helps